# Preserve selection when sorting a WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

When sorting a WPF datagrid, the standard behaviour is for the selected item to be lost. Using the WinForms DataGridView it was [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819573/selected-rows-when-sorting-datagridview-in-winform-application) to restore the selected item by hooking the CellMouseDown event, but the WPF DataGrid doesn't have one of those.

It is also possible to preserve the sort order by providing custom sort logic in the Sorting event, but is there any way of  preserving the current selection while using the default sort logic?

Clarification: The sort happens when the user clicks the column header.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unique field on that grid, save it before the call to the sort method, sort, and then set the selected item to the object that has that unique field ...

Comment: The difficulty is finding some event to attach a handler to after the default sorting is completed. I can hook Sorting to get the selected item before the sorting starts, but I'd need some event that's triggered after the sort runs to reapply it.

Comment: I guess it depends where and how you call your sorting :) ... you didn't provide that information ...

Comment: The default sort behaviour is applied when the user clicks a column header.

Comment: if i'm not mistaken, you need to implement that, right ? I was under the impression that clicking the header doesn't sort it out of the box ... ?